# How to go around a modem's port forwarding incapabilities

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, cable-modem

This custom cable modem my ISP gave to me does not support **forwarding an external port to a different internal port**. (For example, I can't forward an incoming connection on **port 80 to port 3389 on my main box** and and an incoming connection on **port 21 to port 3389 on my old box**. I need to do this to avoid port blocking.)

I know I could go around this by changing the port of RDP on my machines but I can't because I already have an HTTP server which must run on 80 for internal testing purposes.

I could not find any software updates, I could not get any support from my ISP and I could not find any better cable modems. (Cable modems are very uncommmon compared to ADSL modems.)

So is there any way I can go around this limitation?

Comment: Can you put your own router and switch in between your computers and the modem?

Comment: How will that work? I don't know how to setup such a network. I have a Linksys WAG160N which was my old ADSL modem. Could that work?

Comment: shane is kind of right.. If you put something in the middle, the thing should be a Plain Router, not a Modem/Router device(i.e. not a router with modem built in).  A plain Router instead of an adsl modem built in, has an ethernet socket labelled WAN, and that's where you use a cat5 cable to connect your modem to it.

Comment: Actually you can possibly use an adsl router for that. You use a cat5 cable to connect the modem to a regular port on your modem/router.

Comment: My old ADSL modem doesn't have it. (Because why would I connect another modem to it right? :P) So should I get something like Linksys E1200?

Comment: @AlicanC: I've yet to see an ADSL modem that does not have an Ethernet port...

Comment: @grawity, I meant the WAN port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one computer as a port-translating relay. Configure the router to forward all required  ports (unchanged) to that computer.

Use something like [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) to bounce the connection over to a different port on the other computer as needed.

[example](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES)

```
 socat TCP4-LISTEN:80 TCP4:otherpc:3389
```

---

Update: Grawity points out below that using Windows you can do something like

```
c:\>netsh
netsh>interface portproxy
netsh interface portproxy>add v4tov4 listenport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.100 connectport=3389 protocol=tcp
```

See [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: FWIW, Windows has such a feature built in -- via `netsh interface portproxy` IIRC.

Comment: Looks like a great short-time solution since I'm worried about performance and the power bill of running a computer 24/7 to make everything else work.

Comment: you can run it on a really small netbook.. or similar embedded system that uses like 10watts..

Comment: … like on a 3.5W (5V x 700 mA) $25 [Raspberry pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) B maybe?